# What is the difference between cloning the object with .clone() method and = sign?

Tags: java, methods, clone, cloning

I am really confused about what is the difference between `.clone()` method or simply putting the `=` sign between objects while trying to clone it.

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy an object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Comment: Does possible duplication means it should be down voted?

Comment: Yes sir, I am just a newcomer to this site, but I still appreciate what I get.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you create a new Dog:

```
Dog a = new Dog("Mike");
```

and then:

```
Dog b = a;
```

You'd have one `Dog` and two variables that reference the same `Dog`. Therefore doing:

```
a.putHatOnHead("Fedora");

if (b.hasHatOnHead()) {
    System.out.println("Has a hat: " + b.getHatName());
}
```

Will print that the dog has a Fedora hat, because `a` and `b` reference the same dog.

Instead, doing:

```
Dog b = a.clone();
```

Now you have two dogs clones. If you put a hat on each dog:

```
a.putHatOnHead("Rayden");
b.putHatOnHead("Fedora");
```

Each dog will have its own hat.

Comment: Thank you for this clear instruction, now things got clearer :)

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to explain you:

```
Object obj = new Object();  //creates a new object on the heap and links the reference obj to that object
```

Case 1:

```
Object obj2 = obj;  //there is only one object on the heap but now two references are pointing to it.
```

Case 2:

```
Object obj2 = obj.clone(); //creates a new object on the heap, with same variables and values contained in obj and links the reference obj2 to it.
```

for more info on clone method, you can refer the java api documentation

Comment: Thank you for your effort, now I comfortably can say that I understood the whole concept :)

Answer (score 1):

The `=` sign is the assignment operator in java. Having `a = b` means "I assign to the variable `a` the value of variable `b`. If `b` is an object, then `a = b` makes `a` point to the object that `b` is pointing to. It does **not** copy the object, nor clone it.

If you want to clone an object you either have to do it by hand (ugly), or have to make the class that has to be clonable to implement `Clonable` then call `clone()`.

The advantage on `clone()` over the "ugly" way is that with `clone()` it's the developer of the class to be cloned that defines how cloning has to be done in order to ensure that the copy is a legit and working copy.

Answer (score 0):

With `=` you are just giving the same object a different name. With `.clone` you are creating a new object that is a copy of the original one.

Answer (score -3):

`=` creates a new reference to the same object.
`clone()` creates a new physical object with the same attributes as the earlier one

Comment: When the question have been answered years ago, please don't answer if you don't have anything to add. Everything you say is already included in previous answers.

Comment: _@AnmolParikh_ Just to notify you. Your answer is currently discussed at Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349781/how-do-i-vote-late-answers-when-there-are-much-better-answers