# How to reload the scene to its original state

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I am creating a Solitaire game using JavaFX. I want a <kbd>Restart</kbd> button to start a new game, but also a <kbd>Reset</kbd> button that will restart the same game i.e. **the same scene to its original state**.

<kbd>Restart</kbd> works seamlessly as I was able to call the `start` method but I am unable to get <kbd>Reset</kbd> working.

```
package guisolitaire;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class GUISolitaire extends Application {
    Game game;
    Pane root;
    ScoreTimer timer = new ScoreTimer();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1000, 800);

        root = new Pane(canvas);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");

        game = new Game(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D());
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked(game::handleMouseClicked);

        timer.restart();
        timer.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.GREEN);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Solitaire");
        primaryStage.show();

        Label l = new Label(); // Timer label
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline( 
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, ae -> l.setText("Time elapsed: " + timer.s)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
        );

        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
                
        l.setTranslateX(800);
        l.setTranslateY(765);
        root.getChildren().add(l); 

        Button newGameButton = new Button();
        newGameButton.setText("New Game");
        newGameButton.setTranslateX(10);
        newGameButton.setTranslateY(765);
        root.getChildren().add(newGameButton);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> newGameEvent = ae -> {
            timer.stop();
            timer.restart();
            start(primaryStage);
        };

        newGameButton.setOnAction(newGameEvent);

        Button restart = new Button();
        restart.setText("Restart");
        restart.setTranslateX(100);
        restart.setTranslateY(765);
        root.getChildren().add(restart);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> resetGameEvent = ae -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            timer.stop();
            timer.restart();
        };

        restart.setOnAction(resetGameEvent);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have tried to reset `primaryStage` with the same scene and call the `show` method but that does not restart the game, it does not do anything.

Any ideas on how this may be able to be implemented?

Comment: What is the initial state of the game? Set every variable and node back to it's initial state.

Comment: If I do that, it will start a new game, not the game that was previously started. Thanks though!

Comment: At the start of a game, save the current state. Use that saved state to reset the game.

Comment: I tried saving the game variable to a new variable and making it final, then calling that in the restart button, but that still won't restart the game, rather it doesn't do anything. Maybe I am doing what you're saying incorrectly. Sorry super new to JavaFX!

Comment: My guess is that this copying issue. See if Cloning or Deep Copy will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103443/what-is-the-difference-between-cloning-the-object-with-clone-method-and-sig